# Can I pass a resource as a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, embedded-resource

I am using resources to store SQL for each database type, e.g.

```
var results = connection.Query<bool>(PostgreSql.SomeQuery, new { someParam });
```

The resource `OracleSql`, `MicrosoftSql`, etc. also contain `SomeQuery`.

Can I pass a resource as a parameter, so that I can do something like:

```
public bool DoSomeQuery(resource res) {
    var results = connection.Query<bool>(res.SomeQuery, new { someParam });
    return results;
}
```

or

```
var results = connection.Query<bool>(GetResource(provider).SomeQuery, new { someParam });
```

If not, I would appreciate ideas on how to accomplish this. Helper class, e.g. `getSomeQuery(dbType)`?
Seems like there should be a nicer way (nHibernate and EF won't work for this application).

Comment: take a look at msdn on how to use `Resource.ResourceManager.GetString("my_resource_name", Resource.Culture);`